# Is the effectiveness of a lure module influenced by the number of spawn points in the area?

Tags: pokemon-go

While going around town yesterday, we found a PokéStop that had an active Lure Module on it. It was the first time I used (or in this case, rode along) a Lure Module, but to my disappointment (& personal opinion) not that much Pokémon spawned.

In the immediate neighborhood of that PokéStop not much Pokémon can be found either. The Stop's in a quiet park and hence not much cellular activity is being recorded there. [Assuming cellular activity corresponds to spawn points](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sknib/using_ingress_app_as_a_pok%C3%A9mon_go_maphack_to_find/?st=iqkn92uz&sh=14913494), it is my assumption that around that PokéStop there aren't that many spawn points to be found.

Hence my question: is the effectiveness of a Lure Module influenced by the number of spawn points in the immediate area? I know all theories are pretty speculative at this point, but whatever insights you may draw from your own experience are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im pretty sure they confirmed that Pokemon will spawn more in "high-traffic areas". However, we don't necessarily know how the traffic data was calculated. A quiet park that has little-to-no traffic *over the course of the last year* may still show as a high-traffic area over data spanning *five years*.

Answer (score 3):

I always thought of Lures, and by extension Incense, to be a spawn multiplier. So if the spawn rates in the area are low, the Lure and Incense won't have as a dramatic effect. I'm not sure, or anyone for that matter, what determines spawn rates. Like you mentioned it does seem to correlate with cellular activity which could just be based on population density; mo' people, mo' Pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've noticed, incense seems to help a little, and the lure module seems to help more.

I agree with previous answer, it does seem like cellular activity makes a big difference. It seems like the more heavily developed areas of a city have good spawn rates. Also if u are in downtown or on outskirts. The less there is in the area, the less Pokemon seem to spawn.

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on how much cellular activity is in that area at that time.... For instance me and 5 friends lured 3 stops in a remote park. We could not walk fast enough to catch the Pokémon. When only I went out to the same spot and lured the same 3 stops spawn rate/ rarity was noticeably lower. We have tested this theory on more occasions and the results were pretty constant to above stated theory. Hope that helps!